# Unexpected order of evaluation in ForAll

Tags: evaluation

I noticed that `ForAll` behaves rather unexpectedly when its first argument is a symbol which has been `Set` in an outer scope.

For example, at first I used this expression, which worked as intended:

```
pred1 = ForAll[{x1, x2}, x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0, x1*y1 + x2*y2 >= 0];
Reduce[pred1]
```

> ```
> y2 >= 0 && y1 >= 0
> ```

Then I thought I could generalise this, using a previously defined list:

```
x = {x1, x2};
y = {y1, y2};
pred2 = ForAll[x, And @@ Thread[x >= 0], x.y >= 0]
```

> ```
> ForAll[x, x && 0, x . {y1, y2} >= 0]
> ```

which was not what I expected.

It seems like `ForAll` is localising the first argument, preventing its replacement. I managed to override this behaviour by constructing the arguments of `ForAll` in a list, and then replacing its head:

```
pred3 = ForAll @@ {x, And @@ Thread[x >= 0], x.y >= 0};
SameQ[pred1, pred3]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now this works as before.

However, this solution seems a little hackish. Is this the "canonical" way of achieving what I want? If not, is there a better way?

Comment: "It seems like `ForAll` is localising the first argument, preventing its replacement." - `ForAll[]` has the `HoldAll` attribute, leading to your observations. `With[]` should save you: `With[{x = {x1, x2}, y = {y1, y2}}, ForAll[x, And @@ Thread[x >= 0], x.y >= 0]] // Reduce`.

Comment: I see. Thank you.